# Do gravitational waves stretch and squeeze the other fields (EM and strong) as they pass by?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, general-relativity, gravitational-waves

I have read this question:

[image]

> the gravitational wave really does cause the distance d to change with time. If you shone a light ray between the protons and timed how long it took you'd find that time oscillated as well.

[How does gravitational wave compress space time?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/238769/how-does-gravitational-wave-compress-space-time)

Now as far as I understand, gravitational waves stretch and squeeze spacetime itself (act on the gravitational field), and as they pass by, we can measure changes in the distances on different axes.

My question is about the other fields, that is, the electromagnetic and strong field. A point charge (like the electron) has a static EM field around it (it is an intrinsic property of the electron), that spreads out spherically. Does this EM field get stretched and squeezed as the GW passes by? Same could be asked about the color field of for example a proton, but I am primarily asking about the EM field (color fields are harder to answer because of confinement).

Question:

1. Do gravitational waves stretch and squeeze the other fields (EM and strong) as they pass by?

Comment: would we be able to measure gravitational waves if the the effect of the space variations did not change the electric and magnetic field strengths according tothe classical   formulae?  see LIGO